# How to decorate nested activerecord associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, decorator

I am working with a gallery_collection that has_many collection_objects and has_many enhanced_objects through those collection_objects

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :collection_objects, inverse_of: :gallery_collection
 has_many :enhanced_objects, through: :collection_objects
```

Ultimately in my GalleryCollection view I am exposing individual enhanced_objects and I would like to expose methods that are available via the EnhancedObject decorator. In my particular example I want to be able to call the method `object_record_url`

If I decorate the gallery_collection, I can also decorate the collection_objects by using the `decorates_association` in the GalleryCollectionDecorator

```
class GalleryCollectionDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  delegate_all
  decorates_association :collection_objects, with: CollectionObjectDecorator
```

This works well but I then want to be able to access a specific enhanced_object from the collection_objects and for it to also be decorated.

I tried also using `decorates_association` in CollectionObjectDecorator

```
class CollectionObjectDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all
  decorates_association :enhanced_objects, with: EnhancedObjectDecorator
end
```

but this does not appear to work when I initiate the decoration cascade from the level of GalleryCollection.

I am testing the outcomes in the console at the moment with the following:

```
collection = GalleryCollection.find(3)
decorated_col = collection.decorate
```

-- returns a GalleryCollectionDecorator

```
collection_objects = decorated_col.collection_objects
```

-- returns a CollectionObjectDecorator

```
enhanced_object = collection_objects[0].enhanced_object
```

-- returns an undecorated enhanced_object

```
enhanced_object.object_record_url
```

-- returns a no method error as it doesn't have access to the decorator method

I would like to be able to access the decorator methods of the enhanced_object that I access from the GalleryCollection. Is there are way to do this using a decorates_association, or is there a better, more 'Rails' way to achieve this?

Comment: I never found a way to cascade decoration beyond the immediate association. My approach in the end was decorate liberally in the controller, so I would have access in the gallery_collection views to decorated: gallery_collections, collection_objects and enhanced_objects.

Answer (score 0):

- Reload your code - it might not have picked up the change `decorates_association :enhanced_objects, with: EnhancedObjectDecorator`
- I'd try without delegate_all
- Make sure draper is up to date. Could be a bug in your version? If this was expected behavior, I'd expect it to be documented so check the docs.

Worst case, just write your own ruby for this:

```
def enhanced_objects
  @enhanced_objects ||= enhanced_objects.decorate
end
```